How to execute test by exact name (equals) via command in playwright
I'm trying to execute a specific test by it's name.
The problem is that when I'm executing npx playwright test -g "test" grep (-g) executes all test that has the given string ("test") within their title.
I need to execute only the test that its name equals to "test"
(I don't want to change the name, nor adding tags for this purpose)
test("test", async ({}, testInfo) => console.log(`Name: ${testInfo.title}`));
test("test2", async ({}, testInfo) => console.log(`Name: ${testInfo.title}`));
test("3test", async ({}, testInfo) => console.log(`Name: ${testInfo.title}`));


Good question. I see how to eliminate test2 but not 3test. See this answer. -g '^test$' doesn't work for some reason, but -g 'test$' is allowed. Somehow the ^ is rejected.

Unless all the tests are in the same file, you can provide the path to the specific file in which the specific test is located.

The string you provide to /g is treated as a regex with the /gi switch so you can do things like "t.st" to match test/tasty/tostada. My first guess was to use ^ at the start of the string, but that was finding no results for me.
It turns out the string it is matching against is:
relative\path\to\yourtest.spec.js Name of your test
So in your example you could get just the test called "test" with " test$". That would be the most concise, but would fail if there was another test called "my test". If you know all your tests end with ".spec.js" or ".spec.ts" you could do:
npx playwright test -g "\.spec\..s test$"
Not exactly slick, but it works.
